# Does branch.io needs code changing on app end?

Tags: ionic-framework, branch.io

I am managing a website(a web developer) and we have a mobile app in ionic, I don't have experience in mobile development. My boss wants to integrate branch.io in the website and ios. Does code needs to be change on mobile app also or it would be possible to do only this in webapp? Any pointer will be helpful. Many thanks!

Comment: Could you be more specific about the technology you used? Are all apps developed based on the same ionic codebase?

Comment: @JanisJansen There is a website that is build in wordpress boss wants to integrate branch.io in it, and then there is an app build in ionic by developer that is not available any more. I want to know that in integrating branch.io should i change the code in wordpress or is there is something I have to change in ionic too?

Comment: this depends on whether you link from the Ionic App to you WordPress site and if you would change links when using Branch.io. I generally would say there shouldn't be much trouble but if these two apps are somehow connected there could be the need to change something.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you would like to use Branch for, to get the full functionality of Branch, you will have to install the Web SDK as well as the App SDK. The good news, however, is that this is very easy to do. You can refer to this step by step guide to integrate Branch https://docs.branch.io/apps/cordova-phonegap-ionic/

In case you need help anytime, please reach out to support@branch.io